# How to add contact next to Category in wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a Knowledge base. I managed to add ratings and category to the page.

I would like to add contact person below categories and let the users add comments to the wiki page if possible. How do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your request, you can add SocialCommentControl. Try to edit the page in SharePoint Designer. And insert the snippet below to a DIV tag you created:

`<div class="article-content">
    Comment on this article:<br/>
    <SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl 
        ID="CommentControl" runat="server"/>
</div>`

[Here is a similar request for more information](https://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/adding-ratings-and-comments-to-sharepoint-publishing-pages)